# Jasper report table can't fit on the current page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper report that is iterating over a list of data returned by a query and displaying the data in tabular format. Depending on the number of table rows the contents of the table might be split across two pages.

Is there a way to prevent this data splitting and cause the entire table to appear on the next page if it doesn't all fit on the current page?

The detail band of my report is as follows:

```
<detail>
        <band height="100" splitType="Prevent">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="800" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3e389075-14ca-4f57-9d02-175fbc34a639"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="output" uuid="acf7113d-1f5a-4acc-ad2c-70efb491bb4f">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{output})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="60" width="800">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="20" width="555" height="20" uuid="156e4ef8-b8d9-4dc4-8a50-4f27e0f36a83"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reference}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="200" height="20" uuid="3e389075-14ca-4f57-9d02-175fbc34a639"/>
                            <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="unitDetails" uuid="acf7113d-1f5a-4acc-ad2c-70efb491bb4f">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{units})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="40" width="800">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="ead7d8ba-12e2-4a0e-af92-66a50b34148f"/>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{businessUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                    <componentElement>
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="800" height="20" uuid="85e29233-08b3-4717-b260-82c9e4a003c5"/>
                                        <jr:table>
                                            <datasetRun subDataset="codeDetails" uuid="1f5dfa57-f961-4574-b663-8637b2aa6f6e">
                                                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{codes})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                            </datasetRun>
                                            <jr:column width="100" uuid="f832562c-1459-44a4-89df-fe5feadfe7ee">
                                                <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                                    <textField>
                                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e2ce6b92-bf8a-45f8-936a-af99b2ced4e7"/>
                                                        <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                                </jr:detailCell>
                                            </jr:column>
                                            <jr:column width="150" uuid="b8c51d7d-f4d2-47c9-90a8-2449dff2a9f9">
                                                <jr:columnHeader height="20">
                                                    <staticText>
                                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="2fc57842-d68d-4398-a0df-4eddd74316fd"/>
                                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                                        <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
                                                    </staticText>
                                                </jr:columnHeader>
                                                <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                                    <textField>
                                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="b2953321-ce5d-4e5f-94e3-8b48b49bbf90"/>
                                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                                </jr:detailCell>
                                            </jr:column>
                                            <jr:column width="150" uuid="f8e255a7-951d-43ad-962b-f4ee32efaa80">
                                                <jr:columnHeader height="20">
                                                    <staticText>
                                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="69deede1-0fbc-4fd0-b430-4f0f3cacdc4f"/>
                                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                                        <text><![CDATA[Approved]]></text>
                                                    </staticText>
                                                </jr:columnHeader>
                                                <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                                    <textField>
                                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="200263e0-f9fb-4626-8cee-3eb838d51add"/>
                                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{approved}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                                </jr:detailCell>
                                            </jr:column>
                                            <jr:column width="150" uuid="b4d8feb1-4134-4302-bad1-902685238d3e">
                                                <jr:columnHeader height="20">
                                                    <staticText>
                                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="096581a7-beec-43bc-a17e-ce96c4384838"/>
                                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                                        <text><![CDATA[Rejected]]></text>
                                                    </staticText>
                                                </jr:columnHeader>
                                                <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                                    <textField>
                                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="3c5d019f-c4af-479b-b180-d52a6606d4e0"/>
                                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{rejected}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                                </jr:detailCell>
                                            </jr:column>
                                        </jr:table>
                                    </componentElement>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

The report output looks like the following where the bottom of the page has the table headings but not the contents because the contents don't fit.

[image: Report Output]

Comment: So it looks like there's a group around the detail. The group band has some properties to work with, as keep together , minimum details or min height to start new page

Comment: @Turo do you have an example of how and where to use the group? Min height to start new page sounds good.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. You made your report by nested MapCollectionDatasources. This approach only works with one Datasource and the nesting is done by the jasperreports-grouping. You could try add a break with a printWhenExpression and force the pageBreak by counting the rows yourself and setting a flag in the appropriate datasource, but that doesn't sound good to me...

Comment: @Turo I don't understand the detail bands, could I have a nested one inside the last nested loop and set a height on that and the appropriate split type. There must be a way to do what I want it to do.

Comment: You could nest a detail-band by changing you inner jr:list to a subreport, but the straight way would be using one DataSource and grouping